# Apply CSS to input type disable Checkbox

Tags: html, css, angular2-forms

I am working on Angular 2 reactive form. I need to apply CSS when input type is disabled but I am struggling to achieve this for checkbox and radio.

### HTML generated code

```
<input _ngcontent-c6="" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-name="01cb437e-0015-4c45-9828-fb2d1d" name="undefined" value="9b474b57-3072-4958-a265-0d74ds9abfd6" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
<span _ngcontent-c6="" class="checkmark2"></span>
```

Following code works with input tag

```
span.checkmark2{
background: greenyellow;
}
```

Following code style doesn't work

```
input[type='checkbox']:disabled span.checkmark2{
 background: greenyellow;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sibling operator `+` to select the span
`input[type='checkbox']:disabled + span.checkmark2`